# Floating Unordered lists

Tags: css

I have a Header, and I'm trying to put some text floating in the left of the header and a imput in the right. Here's the code:

```
<header>
   <ul>
     <li id='left'>
       <h2>Example</h2>
     </li>
     <li id='right'>
       <form>
         <input></input>
       </form>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </header>
```

So, what i'm doing is this:

```
header ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:97%;
}
header li{
  display:inline-block;
}

header li #left {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}

header li #right{
  float:right;
  width:50%;
}
```

But this just don't work. I've looked here for other examples, but none of theirs work, so i'm here to put my code and hope for a help. Thanks, and a disclaimer, I'm a rookie in css yet.

Comment: seems to be working here https://jsfiddle.net/1bz91jfp/1/

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/h814sxj3/

Comment: you are using wrong way to access the #left and #right id because these ids are on li                                      

try to this 

header li#left {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}

header li#right{
  float:right;
  width:50%;
}

Comment: You have spaces in your css after the `li` so it isn't selecting correctly.

Comment: header li #left to header li#left; header li #right to header li#right

Comment: I've deleted the blank space between li#right and the header just dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

check out this

**CSS**

```
header ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:97%;
}
header li{
  display:inline-block;
}

header li#left {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
h2{margin:0}
header li#right{
  float:right;
  width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/5bq6p1gt/

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the help.I'm putting a screen of the header here.

http://postimg.org/image/po0elgnip/

the only difference is that i've put a background-color: purple to be more easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:96%;
}
header li{
  display:inline-block;
}

header li#left {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}

header li#right{
  float:right;
  width:50%;
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <ul>
     <li id='left'>
       <h2>Example</h2>
     </li>
     <li id='right'>
       <form>
         <input></input>
       </form>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </header>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help! In the end, won't worked. I'll put a screenshot of the header here to be more clearer.

http://postimg.org/image/7v8l4jt4x/

if you see, the text and the input are side-by-side, and i can't move the input from there.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header li {
  display: table-cell;
}
#right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <ul>
     <li id='left'>
       <h2>Example</h2>
     </li>
     <li id='right'>
       <form>
         <input type="text">
       </form>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following updated CSS will work for you. Lets try
I have gone through the purple background and floating for input filed to right. 
CSS

```
header ul { list-style-type:none; width:99%; }<br />
header li{ display:inline-block;}<br />
header li #right{ float:right; width:50%;}<br />
header li #left { float:left; width:50%; }<br />
header ul { list-style-type:none; width:97%; }<br />
header li{ display:inline-block;}<br />
header li#right{ float:right; width:50%; }<br />
header li#left { float:left; width:50%; }<br />
input { float:right; }<br /><br />
```